# Running Next.JS app on Apache VPS server, can't get HTTPS to work

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https

I have a Next.JS app running on a VPS server on port 1234. I have reversed proxied it via the Apache include for the subdomain with the following lines:

`SSLProxyEngine on`

`ProxyPass /.well-known !`

`ProxyPass / http://SUBDOMAIN.ca:1234/`

`ProxyPassReverse / http://SUBDOMAIN.ca/`

The app works fine when I go to http://SUBDOMAIN.ca but when I go to https://SUBDOMAIN.ca I get a 403 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the complete virtualhost blocks for both http and https.

Comment: That is all I have in the include for that subdomain. Where would I find the virtualhost blocks for http and https?